# Using Session_regenerate_id()

Tags: session-hijacking

Why is it always recommended that **session_regenerate_id()** should be used before the user's session is created. 
As per my perception, session_regenerate_id() should be used once the user session id is created, and we need to re-generate it so as to mitigate the session fixation attack by the hacker.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you've gotten recommendation from, but the [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id#refsect1-function.session-regenerate-id-examples) manual shows it being used after session_start, so your assumptions would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have read the session_start() has to be called before anything else. The main idea is to create a new id each time so that if a hacker is on the same network, they will not have a static id to use to gain entry to your site. A good explanation of how this is done.

https://youtu.be/8dMsHmlxY0s

and here is an excellent answer that goes into more detail than the video:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492488/2654453